# Verb for thing bouncing in your hand before falling

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

Looking for a verb that describes the action that sometimes precedes a thing falling from your hands. It looks like juggling or bouncing, but I’m not sure if those words fit in the following context:

“The phone _____ in her hand, before falling to the ground.”

Comment: She may have *fumbled* the phone, but did the darn thing do any juggling or bouncing of its own?

Comment: *wobbled*, *teetered*, *danced around*, *jiggled* ... I wouldn't object to reading *bounced* but I concur with @YosefBaskin on the unacceptability of *juggled*.

Comment: M-W does have "to hold or balance precariously" for *juggle* and the dictionary.com definition of *bobble* seems to support this sense. Perhaps like someone's first attempt at juggling?

Comment: @DjinTonic The phone may have been juggled in her hand or she may have juggled it in her hand but unless than phone was systematically throwing and catching miniature bowling pins or it somehow rearranged a busy schedule of appointments or a tight budget to fit in one more item, *it* did not juggle in her hand and juggle does not fit the context sentence given in the question.

Comment: @Smartybartfast I wouldn't use *juggle* here either. I was pointing out that the dictionary.com definition of *bobble* uses *to juggle* and was trying to imagine how it could apply. *Juggle* is something intentional to me.

Comment: Please explain what would be wrong with “The phone bounced in her hand…"

Answer (score 7):

> The phone **bobbled** in her hand, before falling to the ground.

**bobble** (v)

> 1: BOB
> 2: FUMBLE   [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bobble)

> *North American [with object]* Mishandle (a ball) [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/bobble)

> To juggle or fumble (a batted or thrown baseball) momentarily, usually
> resulting in an error. [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/bobble)

> To drop or almost drop a ball that you are trying to catch or stop
> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/bobble)

---

> Edmund's hand scraped against a ring of keys, still dangling from the
> lock. He wrenched them out. They **bobbled** in his hand and fell
> somewhere to the unseen floor with an echoing clatter. [Robert Evert;
> *Riddle in Stone*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Riddle_in_Stone/gyOwKB24_gcC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22bobbled%20in%20his%20hand%22%20fell&pg=PT291&printsec=frontcover)

> I smirked and tossed another bear at him, which he **bobbled** in his
> hands, dropping his mobile then bashing his head on the tabletop when
> he bent to pick it up, and almost falling off his chair when he pulled
> back, overcompensating. [Erik Schubach; *Flotilla*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Flotilla_Paying_the_Toll/rIJxDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=bobbled%20in%20his%20hand%20falling&pg=PT82&printsec=frontcover)

> It **bobbled** in his hand nearly dropping, but he was able to snatch
> it before it crashed to the floor. [MJ Fletcher; *The
> Cartographer's Compass*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Cartographer_s_Compass/GOh6DQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22bobbled%20in%20his%20hand%22%20dropping&pg=PT54&printsec=frontcover)

> He didn't drop his sword but his grip on it weakened and it
> **bobbled** in his hand. [Christopher Pike; *Red Queen*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Red_Queen/qgR0AgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22bobbled%20in%20his%20hand%22%20dropping&pg=PA504&printsec=frontcover)

> A bobble is formed by adding several stiches onto an unsuspecting stitch, working them back and forth and...
>
> Even the word *bobble* doesn't bode well. It means to make a mess of
> something, to mishandle it. When a horse makes a misstep before a
> race, it's called a bobble. Likewise, an athlete **bobbles** when
> **fumbling** the ball. To **bobble** is to **lose one's grip**, which is what many people think you've done when you start adding bobbles to
> everything. I certainly thought so. [Clara Parkes; *The Yarn
> Whisperer: My Unexpected Life in Knitting*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Yarn_Whisperer/8dF5AAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22to%20bobble%20is%22&pg=PT21&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: Is that geography specific?  I've never heard that verb (EN-AU native).  I have heard of a "bobble" as a type of hair tie (a long time ago).

Comment: @Kingsley "North American [with object] Mishandle (a ball)" Looks like it.

Comment: @Kingsley The OED also labels this sense as *U.S.*

Comment: @DjinTonic Uh… hardly…